# AntiforgeryToken not generating __RequestVerificationToken hidden field Blazor Server

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, antiforgerytoken

I have an app built using .NET8 Blazor with InteractiveServerRenderMode.

**App.razor** is configured like in Template you get when you create Blazor Server App with Global Interactivity and Identity.

I have one Toolbar component where I am trying to add **SignOut Functionality** with following form

```
<AuthorizeView>
<Authorized>
<form action="Account/Logout" method="post">
    <AntiforgeryToken />
    <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@currentUrl" />
   <button type="submit">Sign out</button>
</form>
</Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

But when I submit this form with Sign out button I get following error

> BadHttpRequestException: Invalid anti-forgery token found when reading
> parameter "string returnUrl" from the request body as form.

This error is right as when I inspect element I don't see *__RequestVerificationToken* field. It is not beind rendered I even tried to use `@attribute [RequireAntiforgeryToken]`
but it is still not working.

I also tried to register it in Program.cs as

```
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
//app.UseAuthentication();
//app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();
app.Run();
```

Anyone who can point what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

> BadHttpRequestException: Invalid anti-forgery token found when reading parameter "string returnUrl" from the request body as form.

According to the error message, you should make sure you have put the `app.UseAntiforgery();` middleware with the right order inside the program.cs.

Please note, according to this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/50612), you need also put `app.UseAntiforgery()` after `app.UseAuthentication()` middleware to avoid this kind of issue.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
...
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

// Add additional endpoints required by the Identity /Account Razor components.
app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();

app.Run();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I am not using app.UseAuthentication(); but when I tried it my [Authorize] attribute failed and redirected me back to Login Page.